# R : How to get values related to last peak of density plot?

Tags: r

I would like to extract the data related to the last peak of my density plot but i don't know how to do that. I found solution for the first peak but not the last. Usually i have 3 peaks (but not always), and i need to get all the data related to the last peak because they are related to patients with potential diseases. [enter image description here][1]

Maybe package exists to do that?

thanks for your help !
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcf20.png

here the first 30 of my data :

```
> data
    V1
1   11
2   35
3   35
4   35
5    6
6   75
7   49
8   74
9   82
10  49
11  75
12   8
13  74
14  37
15  73
16   7
17  47
18  47
19  72
20  48
21  46
22   9
23  73
24  49
25  73
26  51
27  50
28   9
29  73
30  47



Data: as.numeric(as.matrix(data)) (217 obs.);   Bandwidth 'bw' = 7.528

       x                y            
 Min.   :-18.58   Min.   :6.922e-06  
 1st Qu.: 12.21   1st Qu.:3.096e-03  
 Median : 43.00   Median :8.166e-03  
 Mean   : 43.00   Mean   :8.110e-03  
 3rd Qu.: 73.79   3rd Qu.:1.208e-02  
 Max.   :104.58   Max.   :2.061e-02  


> dput(data)
structure(list(V1 = c(11L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 6L, 75L, 49L, 74L, 
82L, 49L, 75L, 8L, 74L, 37L, 73L, 7L, 47L, 47L, 72L, 48L, 46L, 
9L, 73L, 49L, 73L, 51L, 50L, 9L, 73L, 47L, 7L, 14L, 72L, 48L, 
45L, 50L, 10L, 11L, 50L, 37L, 75L, 37L, 50L, 10L, 72L, 48L, 35L, 
7L, 49L, 47L, 71L, 48L, 48L, 70L, 49L, 46L, 50L, 75L, 50L, 78L, 
8L, 15L, 9L, 51L, 8L, 50L, 8L, 75L, 8L, 15L, 79L, 8L, 50L, 9L, 
8L, 16L, 7L, 50L, 7L, 38L, 9L, 38L, 50L, 37L, 10L, 37L, 48L, 
77L, 8L, 48L, 10L, 48L, 11L, 70L, 8L, 46L, 46L, 73L, 7L, 73L, 
48L, 9L, 7L, 50L, 7L, 75L, 75L, 8L, 75L, 7L, 75L, 19L, 75L, 8L, 
50L, 8L, 49L, 48L, 48L, 73L, 49L, 50L, 49L, 49L, 73L, 52L, 49L, 
73L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 4L, 20L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 28L, 4L, 28L, 57L, 
4L, 5L, 28L, 21L, 40L, 4L, 34L, 5L, 21L, 31L, 28L, 27L, 23L, 
47L, 27L, 21L, 28L, 43L, 16L, 33L, 22L, 45L, 6L, 29L, 34L, 42L, 
22L, 5L, 29L, 36L, 43L, 4L, 50L, 75L, 50L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 31L, 25L, 
8L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 31L, 31L, 10L, 26L, 9L, 52L, 52L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 78L, 76L, 76L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 11L, 
51L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-217L))
```

Comment: If this is from R's `density` function, it should return x and y coordinates as values.  You can find the peaks using them; A point `t` is a peak if `y[t-1] < y[t] and y[t] > y[t+1]`.  You can find all such points and pick the third one.  If you provide a sample data, people can help you for more in detail.

Comment: Kota Mori : thanks for your answer, i edited my post with data :)

Comment: `dput(data)` will give you more usable data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, store the result of `density` function as a variable. This variable (`d`) contains the x and y coordinates of the density estimates.
Second, loop over the y values to find points larger than both the previous
and next values. In the code, I allowed equality too, just in case some peaks may be flat.

```r
data <- c(11,35,35,35,6,75,49,74,82,49,
          75,8,74,37,73,7,47,47,72,48,
          46,9,73,49,73,51,50,9,73,47)

d <- density(data)
peaks <- NULL
for (i in 2:(length(d$y)-1)) {
  if (d$y[i-1] <= d$y[i] & d$y[i] >= d$y[i+1]) {
    peaks <- cbind(peaks, c(d$x[i], d$y[i]))
  }
}
peaks
# result:
# each column is a peak point
#          [,1]        [,2]        [,3]
#[1,] 9.8433702 46.92771112 70.90705938
#[2,] 0.0074287  0.01527099  0.01276465

# show the peak in a graph
plot(d)
points(peaks[1,], peaks[2,])

# third peak, if any
peaks[,3]
#[1] 70.90705938  0.01276465
# you can use this elsewhere you want for further analysis
```

[image]

Comment: wow thanks a lot ! I just changed your code to get the "whole" peak started from the minimum but it did exactly what i need thanks !

Comment: Glad to hear that!  If you think this solves your question, please click the accept button.